# Why web browser can't read "data-mage-init" attribute?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am working on JavaScript add-on. while trying to read HTML loaded on the browser via chrome's developer tool -> element tab.

the code was executing fine. but I can't see attribute. it is a just simple custom attribute, right?

this question is only for the knowledge base.

[image]

on save button there should have extra attribute "data-mage-init" which help to execute some javascript.

Comment: check by view source(Ctrl + U).

Comment: @kunj thanks it worked. but do you know why it not working in element tab? is it bug from chrome? FireFox also don't show  "data-mage-init" in inspector.

Comment: Not Sure about it but Magento call this js for that

`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init.js`

And this file calls this one.

`lib/web/mage/apply/main.js`

Main JS process for `data-mage-init` and I think remove that attribute from HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento removing that `data-mage-init` attribute from `lib/web/mage/apply/main.js` this file and from this function:

```
function getData(el) {
        var data = el.getAttribute(dataAttr);

        el.removeAttribute(dataAttr);

        return {
            el: el,
            data: JSON.parse(data)
        };
    }
```

You can see `el.removeAttribute(dataAttr);` code in that function.

I think Magento removing that for security and minify HTML. Maybe there are other reasons for that.

Comment: That is correct +1.